# Как вернуть из метода форматированный Date( не String )

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

Добрый день, дамы и господа!

Есть задача - необходимо поместить в DB Oracle дату - строго в формате date  и строго такого формата - 01.01.1900.

При попытке создать дату, переформатировать ее и вернуть из функции - возвращается всегда String,  то есть как вернуть именно Date - неясно

Если кто сталкивался, напишите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему.

P.S. Если переопределять вывод в самом Date  с помощью .toString - ну, тут понятно, что этот вариант не подходит.

PSPS. java Time - тот, что в java 8 - Тоже пробовал и тоже при переформате стринг возвращает

Спасибо!

Comment: `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(date_column) values (TO_DATE(<date_string>, 'mm.dd.yyyy'))` ?

Comment: Не уточнил наверное, что это все нужно сделать с помощью java. Никаких прямых запросов к бд

Comment: "Строго формат date" и "строго формат 01.01.1900" - несовместимые вещи.

Answer (score 3):

Дата не имеет формата. Дата - это конкретный день, конкретного года. Если Вы говорите о "формате" даты, то Вы говорите о формате ее **строкового** представления.

Поэтому фраза

> необходимо поместить в DB Oracle дату такого формата - 01.01.1900.

бессмысленна. Вам в БД нужно записать значение. А как это значение будет отображаться на клиенте, это уже вопросы к клиенту

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю, насколько это бессмысленно
Дело в том, что как я понимаю, данные в БД должны храниться именно в таком виде, потому что уже есть софт, который Собирает данные из бд и парсит именно такой вид даты, с точками, а не с тире допустим

Не зря же архитектор поставил именно такую задачу

Однако действительно, сейчас попробую конкретно дату неформатированную закинуть и посмотрю что будет

Comment: @МаксимФролов Если есть софт который `парсит дату в определенном формате`, то это значит, что софт работает не с датой, а со строкой. И отдавать ему нужно **строку**

Comment: Тоже верно. Но в бд не зря же хранится именно sql.Date

Забираем то мы дату, преобразуем в строку, работаем со строкой и опять преобразуем в дату и кидаем на бд

Comment: @МаксимФролов И возникает вопрос, а зачем мы преобразовывали в строку? Дата должна хранится как Date. Если кто-то не умеет работать с этим типом, то это не проблемы БД и, тем более, не проблемы хранения