# Форматирование LocalDateTime перед сохранением в базу в Spring Boot приложением

Tags: java, hibernate, дата, форматирование

Сохраняю в базу дату и время события, для этого в классе использую `LocalDateTime`, в базе это выглядит вот так `2018-09-05 10:42:58.616000`, есть ли способ, как-то форматировать дату перед сохранением, чтобы её формат был `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class WorkTable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private LocalDateTime enter;
private LocalDateTime exit;

private boolean onWork;
}
```

Дело в том, что я планирую использовать метод поиска по таблице, по указанному времени и поэтому я хотел бы избавиться от секунд.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть из метода форматированный Date( не String )](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788182/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-date-%d0%bd%d0%b5-string)

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, это не совсем то, я малость нубас в этом деле, и возможно я не в правильную сторону копаю, дело в том, что я планирую использовать метод поиска по таблице, по указанному времени и поэтому я хотел бы избавиться от секунд.

Comment: @AndreyPopov а зачем форматировать дату? Поиск и так будет работать через больше-меньше `>` `<` , формат даты не важен.

Comment: [LocalDateTime::truncateTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) если вам нужно переформатировать дату перед сохранением в бд.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
String formattedDateTime = enter.format(formatter);
enter = LocalDateTime.parse(formattedDateTime, formatter);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, что поля типа `LocalDateTime` мапируются на колонки таблицы, тип которых `TIMESTAMP`. Тоесть формат даты, который вы видите в базе данных, выполняя обычный `SELECT * FROM WORK_TABLE` вручную, определяется той программой, в которой вы этот запрос выполняете. Но в вашем коде, в `ResultSet`, вы получите всё тот же `TIMESTAMP`, который сможете отформатировать на свой вкус как вам хочется.